# RecyclerView not updating after calling notifyDataChanged

Tags: android, android-asynctask

`RecyclerView` is not refreshing the data after getting response on the `AsynTask`, I call the method `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter but not response.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? It's basically impossible to help without more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** good idea is to search for previous questions regarding this
**second** idea try calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onPostExecute` overrided method. If this does not work please provide your feedback

Theory
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Excersice
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html